# PHP validate string lightweight

Tags: php

I want to find the most lightweight solution to validate a string as `a letter or number` + `?`. Eg: `a?` or `1?` etc.

Comment: Are there really heavy solution to check just 2 chars?

Comment: You can look into regular expression. here are some examples on [how it works](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]\?$/', $str)) {
    // yup, it's a letter or number + ?
}
```

Comment: You can add also the i modifier to catch also the Uppercase chars.

Comment: Regex is probably not the most lightweight solution here? In any case, add an `i` in the end of the pattern to make it case-insensitive.

Comment: Whatever the OP means by "lightweight"... And yes, an `/i` may or may not be appropriate, I'll leave that up to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

slighty faster than regular expression is function:

```
// return true or false
function validate($str) {
    $str0 = ord($str[0]);
    return(
        (
            ($str0 >= 97 && $str0 <= 122) or
            ($str0 >= 48 && $str0 <= 57)
        ) &&
        (
            $str[1] == '?'
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Since you edit your answer, now your solution is a lot faster. Check this out: Time ord: 0.169085025787
Time regex: 0.260627031326

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago, i've written a lightweight-validation class. Maybe you can use it.

For example:

```
$oValidator = new Validator();
$oValidator->isValid('a', 'alpha_numeric|max_length[1]'); //true
$oValidator->isValid('1', 'alpha_numeric|max_length[1]'); //true
$oValidator->isValid('ab', 'alpha_numeric|max_length[1]'); //false
$oValidator->isValid('1337', 'alpha_numeric|max_length[1]'); //false
```

**Example:**
http://sklueh.de/2012/09/lightweight-validator-in-php/

**github:**
https://github.com/sklueh/Lightweight-PHP-Validator

Answer (score -1):

OK This is **the fastest way**

```
$allowed_char = Array();
for($i=ord('a');$i<=ord('z');$i++) $allowed_char[chr($i)] = true;
for($i=ord('0');$i<=ord('9');$i++) $allowed_char[chr($i)] = true;

function validate($str) {
    global $allowed_char;
    return $allowed_char[$str[0]] && $str[1] == '?' && !isset($str[2]);
}
```

---

Regexp = 2.0147299766541s

This solution = 1.6041090488434s

So it's 20% faster than Regexp solution :)

Comment: Including the construction of the array? Why not make a complete static lookup table? BTW, "lightweight" doesn't necessarily mean "fastest". ;o)